# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error not resolved

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){

int i,n;
char * buffer=NULL;
i=0;
cout<<"enter the character length you wish to store dynamically"<<endl;
cin>>i;

buffer= (char*) malloc(i+1);
if(buffer=NULL)
exit(1);
for(n=0;n<i;++n)
buffer[n]=rand()%26+'a';
buffer[i]='\0';

cout<<"the string is "<<buffer<<endl;
free(buffer);
return 0;}
```

I am getting segmentation fault:
Output:
enter the character length you wish to store dynamically
5
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I am not able to figure out the mistake I did?
I tried to run in debugger mode,but there were no core file generated for it.?
Please suggest a solution to it.

Comment: Your error is here: `if(buffer=NULL)`.  This will set `buffer` to `NULL`.  I think you wanted `if (buffer == NULL)`.  Or maybe better, `if (NULL == buffer)`.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer=NULL` is an assignment. It will be evaluated as false and `buffer[n]=rand()%26+'a';` will dereference the assigned `NULL`.

Do comparision `buffer==NULL` instead.